# How do I make an entity teleport in the direction it's facing in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've seen this question answered before for Java, but I haven't found a Bedrock answer. I need this for a lot of projects, but for the sake of this, let's say I'm making a turret. The turret is controlled by an invisible armor stand called "turret", and summons bullets which are also invisible armor stands named "bullet". I can't, however, figure out how to get the bullets to move in the direction they're facing. Here's the syntax I have:
`/execute as @e[name=bullet] run tp @s ^ ^ ^1`
I presume this would work in Java, and I remember this syntax working before, but I believe it was the change of the Bedrock /execute syntax that made it stop working. How would I properly make an entity move forward?

Comment: MCBE probably has the entity selector argument for facing direction. You can provide lots of small ranges and calculate the sine/cosine values yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`/execute at @e[name=bullet] as @e[name=bullet] run tp @s ^ ^ ^1` will work, but only with one armor stand. `as` doesn't change position, rotation, or dimension, only who/what is executing it. `at` changes position, rotation, and dimension, but not who or what executes it. The problem with multiple armor stands is each one executes in order, so stand #1 teleports all bullets 1 block in front of it, then stand #2 teleports all bullets 1 block in front of it. The Wiki explains more in depth here: [Subcommands and forking](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#Subcommands_and_forking)

Edit: a comment responded with a fully functional command, so that is in the next answer.

Comment: Possibly `/execute as @e[name="bullet"] run execute at @s run tp @s ^^^1`?

Comment: @Hipposgrumm yes, that does work. Will edit now.

Comment: @Hipposgrumm actually, looking at it closer, the quote marks and “run execute” aren’t necessary.

Comment: actually, the `run execute` is what makes it work. However yeah I don't think the quotes are needed unless the name has a space in it.

Comment: No, quote from the wiki: Note that ... run execute ... has no effect at all in both Java Edition and Bedrock Edition. For example, the following commands work the same:

execute as @e[type=armor_stand] as @e[type=armor_stand] run summon armor_stand
execute as @e[type=armor_stand] run execute as @e[type=armor_stand] run execute run execute run summon armor_stand

Comment: No, we need the `run execute at <selector>` after `execute as <selector>` because otherwise doing `execute as <other_target> at @s` will run the command at the player that ran the command and will simply fail in a command block. 
Consensus: Needs ingame testing.

Comment: My point is you don’t need run execute between as and at, they can chain. I did in game testing before posting my answer. “/execute as @s at ~ ~ ~” is the same as “/execute as @s run execute at ~ ~ ~”

Answer (score 0):

`/execute as @e[name=bullet] at @s run tp @s ^^^1`  should work.

If we walk through the command, `execute as @e[name=bullet]` makes all of the entities named “bullet” (armor stands in this case) individually run the following commands as themselves, so all `@s` selectors after the `as` only target the stand running it. However `as` doesn’t change the position or rotation of the command, but `at` does. So `at @s` sets the position and rotation to the stand running the command. And lastly, `run tp @s ^ ^ ^1` teleports all the stands one block in the direction they are facing.